# How do I draw multiple rects to the screen in SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I tried to do it first using `SDL_RenderFillRect()` and `SDL_RenderFillRects()`, However it didn't work, I decided to look into using surfaces as in the documentation it states in `SDL_FillRect()`, that it also needs a surface so I am convinced that the key to drawing multiple is by using surfaces. However, I find the documentation hard to understand (I don't even know where to start looking). Can Someone give me a rundown?

Edit: I think I am having this problem as I thought that `SDL_Rect`(s) were read and write turns out it is read only.  Still don't know what to do now

I am coding in c by the way.

Edit: This is what I tried

I don't have concrete code because it doesn't work, however my idea is fundamentally flawed as my thought process was:

1. Make a SDL_Rect array.
2. Make a rect and append it to this array.
3. render it.
4. Do this for different colored arrays.

I believe this doesn't work though. I heard first you need to make a texture or something. I'm not sure yet can you tell me how to do it with SDL_Textures.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates how you've tried to draw multiple rects?

Comment: I don't use SDL: often, but when drawing, you generally construct the image and then "blit" the image to the screen. Meaning you need to draw all rectangles to a buffer or surface and then display the result all at once.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Not with `SDL_RenderFillRect` It just draws a rect filled with the current render draw color. I may be reading more into what you said though. You do need to call `SDL_RenderPresent` to display the frame when you've drawn all the rects you want to.

Comment: @RetiredNinja There you go I gave you an edit

Comment: You can make an example of the code that isn't working and we can help you fix it. It's a really simple API. In each frame call `SDL_RenderClear` before drawing the rectangles and `SDL_RenderPresent` after. In between call `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` to set the color, set the values in a `SDL_Rect` struct, then call `SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rectangle);` for as many different rectangles you want.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - I definitely need to work with SDL2 more. My recollection comes from doing basic planetary animations in SDL in C. At that time, you were responsible for updating the portion of the screen to be redrawn at once. Once written, there was no guarantee you could read back prior data so if you wanted to reuse part of what you drew (like wanting to combine multiple rectangles), you needed to save a copy of what was written, update that and then blit again. My understanding is that SDL2 works similarly. I may have missed the point of the multi-rectangle question though.

Comment: @RetiredNinja What do you mean by "there was no guarantee that you could read back prior data so if you wanted to reuse part of what you drew (like wanting to combine multiple rectangles), you needed to save a copy of what was written". Could you elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain exactly what your goal is, but here's a simple example that demonstrates using `SDL_RenderFillRect` to draw 5 rectangles of different colors and `SDL_RenderFillRects` to draw 5 rectangles of the same color.

Hopefully you can mix and match some of this to get what you're looking for.

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    SDL_Window *win;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL_Init Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 400, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL_CreateWindow Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (renderer == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL_CreateRenderer Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        SDL_Quit();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_Rect single_rect;
    SDL_Rect multi_rect[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        single_rect.w = 50;
        single_rect.h = 50;
        single_rect.x = i * 50;
        single_rect.y = i * 50;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, (Uint8)(i * 50), 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &single_rect);

        multi_rect[i].w = 50;
        multi_rect[i].h = 50;
        multi_rect[i].x = i * 50 + 50;
        multi_rect[i].y = i * 50;
    }
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRects(renderer, multi_rect, 5);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(5000);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: A draw-call per rect?  [Madness!](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.0.18/include/SDL_render.h#L1601-L1622) :)  (in b4 "but some renderer backends batch!")

Comment: @genpfault Yeah, seems like a simple way to put something on the screen that you'd never use once you discovered alternatives.